# In Relativity theory, is chronological relation an order relation?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, closed-timelike-curve

Let $(M,g)$ be a (Lorentz) spacetime, i.e a connected smooth manifold $M$ with a metric tensor field $g$ and a time orientation called future direction which is defined by a smooth timelike vector field $T:\ M\longrightarrow TM$.

The chronological relation $\ll$ is defined as $\forall p,q\in M,\ p\ll q $ iff there exists a smooth future directed timelike curve $\alpha:\ [a,b]\longrightarrow M$ from $p$ to $q$. The future-directedness of $\alpha$ is given by
\begin{align}
\forall s\in I,\big<\alpha'(s),T(p)\big>_{\alpha(s)} < 0,\ \forall p\in M
\end{align}
where $\big\langle,\big\rangle_{\alpha(s)}=g(\alpha(s))$.

I wonder if $\ll$ is an order relation on $M$. It is quite easy to proof the reflexivity $p\ll p\ \ \forall p\in M $ and the transitivity $(p\ll q)\wedge (q\ll r) \Rightarrow p\ll r $. However, I've been struggling with the antisymmetric property $(p\ll q)\wedge (q\ll p)\Rightarrow p=q $. Is it true that $\ll$ is an order relation ?

Comment: Yes in Minkowski space, no in Godel's universe, so not determined in general.

Comment: @WillO sorry but I still yet to get what you mean, what is Godel's universe ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric

Answer (score 0):

In general, no - the antisymmetric property fails if the spacetime admits a [closed timelike curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve). If you forbid such curves (e.g. via the [chronology protection conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture)) then the antisymmetric property holds essentially by definition, and $\ll$ constitutes a partial order.